# Using PrintWriter with files

Tags: java, bufferedreader, printwriter

In case I have the following code:

```
private PrintWriter m_Writer;
m_Writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(k_LoginHistoryFile));
```

I am writing to a local file on server which name is `k_LoginHistoryFile`.
Now, as my program runs it doing writings to this file so how can I delete all the file content between each writes?
I think it is important as I don't want to write to a file which will eventually have current updated information on its beginning + not up to date info at its end.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This expression:

```
new FileWriter(k_LoginHistoryFile)
```

will truncate your file if it exists. It won't just overwrite the start of the file. It's not clear how often this code is executing, but each time it *does* execute, you'll start a new file (and effectively delete the old contents).

Answer (score 1):

> I think it is important as I don't want to write to a file which will eventually have current updated information on its beginning + not up to date info at its end.

If you want to keep a running output file (and you can't keep the file open), consider this constructor: [FileWriter(String, boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)

If the boolean is *true*, your updated information *will* be at the end of the file.